# Finding vector potential from a given magnetic field

Tags: vectors, computational-mathematics, greens-function, electromagnetism

I want to find the **vector potential** from a given **magnetic field** in **three-dimension** in **cartesian coordinates** for two cases.
1) Where the magnetic field is in any analytical form and 
2) When the magnetic field is **any random number** (numerical).